# Using SlickGrid Select2 in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, slickgrid

I am trying to define a select2 column in a slickgrid table within a Jupyter notebook.

When I go to init the column with $input = $(''); I get thr following object :

n.fn.init [select]
0: select
length: 1

When I use the same $input = $(''); outside of Jupyter in a static html page I get:

n.fn.init [select]
0: select.select2.hidden-accessible
length: 1

Of course the Select2 editor created from the $input blows up in Jupyter but works fine outside of Jupyter.

The code in both(Jupyter, static html page) is exactly the same.

I see nowhere in my jquery-1.12.4.min where the select2.hidden-accessible is defined.  How do I trace where in JQuery the assignment is made.  The two major distinctions between the static html page an the Jupyter html is the static page is a standard container of main-app and Jupyter wraps all html within a Jupyter output container.  Of course the Jupyter html is dynamically created and displayed.

Any help would be great.

Comment: a code sample would be good

Comment: just checking you are using the select2 editor? this is in the 6pac slickgrid repo.

Comment: I am using the 6pac slickgrid repo and am working with the slick grid sample for using select2. It works fine outside Jupyter bur fails in Jupyter.  Exact same code.  I have run the chrome debugger and have some very detailed trace.  I know exactly where it fails but not why. I fail on the '$input.select2({' call in the jupyter version. The '$input = $('<select></select>');' call returns two different objects for the slickgrid sample and the Jupyter version.  Don't know why.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know what Jupyter is and we never worked with it. If you have 2 instances of jQuery it might be the problem, for example with WebPack we need to provide jQuery to the global so that it won't recreate a new and different jQuery instance every time, this article explains it https://makandracards.com/makandra/69621-webpack-how-to-avoid-multiple-versions-of-jquery